# Changing config of the parent class

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to create a base class for list of users. I know how to overwrite 
or add some config on the child class. I some child class I need to add or removed some column to base grid. How can I get the parent `columns` config and modify it in child classes?

Comment: please post your child class code

Answer (score 0):

Child class can override any config option of the base class so if you need different columns just configure them on child, they take precedence over the base class.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want overwrite parent `column` attribute, I want only add/remove some column.

Comment: I don't know how you extend the class but if you are using initComponent you can remove columns in it during class instantiation.

If you want to do it at runtime it is also possible: `grid.headerCt.items.removeAt(index of column to remove)`